# cygwin 64 bit - can't install Pillow via pip

Tags: python, gcc, cygwin, pip, python-imaging-library

I can't seem to install pip on cygwin 64-bit no matter which of the gcc compilers i install. i've tried all of the ones that come up when is search for g++

does anyone know which one i should use? or if i'm going about this completely the wrong way?

when building pip i get errors like this:

```
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python-2.7.8-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python-2.7.8-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python-2.7.8-1.x86_64/src/Python-2.7.8=/usr/src/debug/python-2.7.8-1 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DHAVE_LIBZ -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-build-AceIfG/Pillow/libImaging -I/c/Users/guy/Envs/hippo_dev/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.c -o build/temp.cygwin-1.7.35-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.o
In file included from /c/Users/guy/Envs/hippo_dev/include/Python.h:58:0,
                 from outline.c:20:
/c/Users/guy/Envs/hippo_dev/include/pyport.h:886:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
 #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
  ^
In file included from /c/Users/guy/Envs/hippo_dev/include/Python.h:58:0,
                 from libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10,
                 from libImaging/Imaging.h:14,
                 from libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.c:15:
/c/Users/guy/Envs/hippo_dev/include/pyport.h:886:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
 #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
  ^
In file included from /c/Users/guy/Envs/hippo_dev/include/Python.h:58:0,
                 from libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10,
                 from libImaging/Imaging.h:14,
                 from libImaging/Bands.c:19:
/c/Users/guy/Envs/hippo_dev/include/pyport.h:886:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
 #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
  ^
In file included from /c/Users/guy/Envs/hippo_dev/include/Python.h:58:0,
                 from _imaging.c:76:
/c/Users/guy/Envs/hippo_dev/include/pyport.h:886:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
 #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
  ^
```

Comment: for reference, this doesn't happen on cygwin 32-bit.  it installs fine there.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote you installed and tried multiple compilers. If you mean compilers from setup.exe, then "gcc" is the Cygwin compiler with same number of bits as the Cygwin it's installed from (i.e. cygwin32 compiler on cygwin32 and cygwin64 compiler on cygwin64). Other compilers have different names, for example x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc, or x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc.

The problem is probably that -- if you want to compile using a Cygwin compiler -- you should be using Python headers from Cygwin Python. It looks like `/c/Users/guy/Envs/hippo_dev/include/` contains Python headers from some 32-bit Python. Generally speaking, you shouldn't mix in any non-Cygwin-provided headers or libraries unless you're sure they're compatible.

Comment: thanks for replying me on the #cygwin. i only used packages from the cygwin setup.exe installer so they must all be cygwin? if i was using the 64-bit version of cygwin, does it automatically install the 64-bit version of python and related python header libraries? I didn't notice any 64-bit specific python headers or dev packages.

Comment: Yes, everything setup.exe installs has the same amount of bits as the installed Cygwin itself, if applicable, so the python package on 64-bit Cygwin installs 64-bit Python (same goes for headers). See https://gist.github.com/elieux/b11c3a5f7bd476f5068e for difference between 32-bit and 64-bit versions of my Python headers.